# Session control and homepage

Tags: express, session

I want to redirect already logged users which try to access the (registration) homepage of the application (the root) towards their (internal) client homepage. I added the same session control that works on other page to the root route, with no results at all:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.session);
  User.findById(req.session.userId)
  .exec(function (error, user) {
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
    } else {
      if (user === null) {
        return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/views/index.html'));
      } else {
        console.log(user);
        return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../views/clientPage.html'));
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I noticed also that this code is never accessed: the console logs you see in the code are never printed out; moreover if I comment the whole route, the root homepage remains still attainable.

How can I subordinate the access to the homepage to the lack of an existing session?